# Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 install script 'node scripts/install.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am trying to install node dependencies in a server with `npm install` with `node 6.11.3`.

But I get this error:
[image]

Also I switched to `node v12.9.1` with `nvm` but still get the same.

Supported node.js versions as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass):

```
NodeJS    Minimum node-sass version   Node Module
Node 12   4.12+                       72
```

I can't seem to find the solution.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Does the user have permissions for that directory? Also why are you putting Node stuff in the html directory?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes.. I'm running as a superuser with `sudo su`. And that's where I put my project, and hence the node stuff